# Why my gitlab runner try to fetch repo with a different url other than which I configured?

Tags: gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I deployed a gitlab runner and a gitlab instance on the same server using docker, after that, I tried to run a few samples to test my runner, but in the first job it always tells me that it can't access my repository. The weird thing is that it try to access a totally different URL instaed of the one in config.toml.
Here is my config:

```
concurrent = 1
check_interval = 0

[session_server]
  session_timeout = 1800

[[runners]]
  name = "******"
  url = "http://172.17.0.3:8010/"
  token = "*********"
  executor = "docker"
  [runners.custom_build_dir]
  [runners.cache]
    [runners.cache.s3]
    [runners.cache.gcs]
    [runners.cache.azure]
  [runners.docker]
    tls_verify = false
    image = "ubuntu"
    privileged = false
    disable_entrypoint_overwrite = false
    oom_kill_disable = false
    disable_cache = false
    volumes = ["/cache"]
    shm_size = 0
```

The *http://172.17.0.3:8010/* is exact the ip of my gitlab instance inside the docker network.
Here is where the runner try to get my code:

```
Running with gitlab-runner 13.12.0 (7a6612da)
  on third runner 2ieTUrD1
Preparing the "docker" executor
Using Docker executor with image ubuntu:focal ...
Pulling docker image ubuntu:focal ...
Using docker image sha256:7e0aa2d69a153215c790488ed1fcec162015e973e49962d438e18249d16fa9bd for ubuntu:focal with digest ubuntu@sha256:adf73ca014822ad8237623d388cedf4d5346aa72c270c5acc01431cc93e18e2d ...
Preparing environment
00:01
Running on runner-2ieturd1-project-12-concurrent-0 via dfcd09965d50...
Getting source from Git repository
Fetching changes with git depth set to 50...
Reinitialized existing Git repository in /builds/zh****/e****/.git/
fatal: unable to access 'http://8.136.221.242:8010/zh****/e****.git/': Failed to connect to 8.136.221.242 port 8010: Operation timed out
ERROR: Job failed: exit code 1
```

Can anyone help me, thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

Update your /etc/gitlab/gitlab.rb file and set

```
external_url "http://172.17.0.3:8010/"
```

Once you've saved it run

```
sudo gitlab-ctl reconfigure
```